# Node.js events and cluster

Tags: node.js, events, cluster-computing

I am using Node.js with [events-module](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html). I want to use all the cpu-cores, so I have read about [cluster-module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).
 Does these two modules work togheter? If the event is triggered in a different cpu-core?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

No, events triggered through Node.js `EventEmitter` are only fired within one process. You can trigger `message` event from worker to master process with [Cluster API](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) or you can use external message hub i.e. [Redis Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Comment: I have tried Redis with Pub/Sub but it's very slow, compare to the EventEmitter.

Comment: If Cluster API events don't cover your needs then an external message bus is the only option.